# How to get a list of recently added stored procs from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is it possible to get a list of stored procs from a SQL Server database where created/last updated date > yesterday?

`sys.sql_modules` does not seem to have a date. It must be stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will list all of the stored procedures along with their creation and modified dates:

```
SELECT name, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
  AND modify_date >= DATEADD(Day, -1, CONVERT(Date, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY modify_date DESC;
```

**EDIT**: Since `modify_date` will always be equal to or after `create_date`... Also note that you could just use `sys.procedures` as another answer mentioned.

Comment: Since the OP refers to "Yesterday", it's probably a better idea to strip the time part of the day.

Answer (score 5):

`Information_Schema` has several views to help review various objects. `Routines` is one of them

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
Where CREATED > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()-1), 0)
Order by CREATED Desc
```

The last two columns are for Created and Last_Modified.

Answer (score 5):

[`sys.procedures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx) contains `create_date` and `modify_date`

Answer (score 5):

Use `sys.procedures`. More direct than `sys.objects` (you don't need to filter on type) and - while less portable than `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` - the `sys.` catalog views continue to be maintained and extended with information on new features, while `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is not.

For example, to find all the stored procedures created or modified since yesterday at midnight:

```
DECLARE @yesterday DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]), name, create_date, modify_date
    FROM sys.procedures 
    WHERE modify_date >= @yesterday
    ORDER BY modify_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND modify_date >= DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())
ORDER BY modify_date desc
```

Comment: Since the OP refers to "Yesterday", it's probably a better idea to include the whole day.